# How can I have MSBuild always mark a target out of date on build?

Tags: c++, msbuild, googletest

I have some unit tests in a Google Test project. I want to run these tests as part of my msbuild script. I've added the following to my `vcxproj` file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(TargetPath)&quot;"
        IgnoreExitCode="true"
        IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true"
        CustomWarningRegularExpression=": error:"/>
</Target>
```

Unfortunately, since there are no inputs or outputs for `Exec`, it only runs once, and never causes the `vcxproj` itself to be marked out of date.

How can I force this `Exec` to always be out of date (so that it runs every build)?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `DependsOnTargets`attribute w/ dependency on the `vcxproj` that contains code to be tested. That way, each time the code is updated and built, your unit tests will execute.

Comment: That is what is happening now -- AfterBuild is called out in the "build" target created by one of the default targets files. I want the tests to run even if the code has not changed though.